# Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") is not working in IE

Tags: asp-classic, http-headers, http-referer

The Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") is not working in the Internet Explorer.

We have a requirement like, there are two different websites say, www.example1.com and www.example2.com. I have to redirect all the users who uses www.example1.com to www.example2.com, and when we intentionally select www.example1.com in the dropdown list of www.example2.com it should have to open without any redirection.

For this I have used Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") in the www.example1.com so that I can Identify who are requesting www.example1.com based on that I applied redirection. This worked great in All standard browsers like Mozilla and Google Chrome but not applying for Internet Explorer.

I used the below ASP code for www.example1.com

```
<%if(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") <> "http://www.example2.org/") then

URL = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=c184c2d089c7763a81d7701a662b57fe3bf90dbfd8bf60d29948878531e24472&ip=" &           Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
                Set conn = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")       
            conn.open "GET", URL, False, "", "" 
            conn.send         
                UserCountry = conn.ResponseText  
                conArray = Split(UserCountry, ";") 
            if ((conArray(3) = "US")) Then
                response.redirect("http://www.example2.org/")
            end if
end if            
 %>
```

It worked fine in all Browsers except IE. Can any one know regarding this? would you please suggest me the equivalent code for ALL BROWSERS (Including IE) which would give similar results as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on `HTTP_REFERER` being present: user agents aren't required to set it.

Try using `HTTP_HOST` instead: the host header is mandatory since HTTP 1.1.

```
If (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") <> "www.example2.org") Then
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, would you please specify what exactly is host header and how it will be helpful for me.

Comment: @Praveen: There's a list of headers here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers. In a nutshell, the `Host` header should contain the domain name that was used to access that page.

Comment: :I had used HTTP_HOST but it's getting the current page Host name I need a requirement like I need exact domain name of the requested page. HTTP_REFERER renders exact output but not work in IE.Can you specify any method which works for all browsers with actuall output expected.

Comment: @Praveen: The domain name *is* the host name. Are you saying that you need the full url, not just the domain name?

Comment: Yes Luke you are wright!..I mean to say the full url of the requesting page. Would you suggest any method which works for all browsers.

Comment: If you are reaching the code from another page which is performing a Response.Redirect, that is the real issue.  The IIS server will clear the HTTP_REFERER value out prior to reaching the new page  Just the way it was designed.  And the HTTP_HOST just returns the domain name, with the "www" prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link which says HTTP_REFERER is not a mandatory member of the HTTP specification.

You can use server variable SERVER_NAME for your requirement and it should work.

Happy coding !!

Comment: @ Ravia: Thanku for the suggestion, SERVER_NAME only returns the server name , i need a requirement like i want the exact server name of the requested page, can you suggest any method for this?

Comment: In case you know IP address of your server then you may use REMOTE_ADDR or try REQUEST_URI.